# Regular expression that matches 5 (exactly) comma separated currency values

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match 5 occurrences of comma separated currency values.

I do have this reg ex that does the job but I think that's not the great way to do it.

```
^(\$[0-9]{1,3}(?:[,.]?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?,\s?){4}(\$[0-9]{1,3}(?:[,.]?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?)$
```

P.S. I had to split the expression into matching, 4 comma separated occurrences and 1 to sniff out trailing comma (I don't think that's the way to do it)

Some of the valid matching inputs could be,

```
$200,000,$525,$60000,$120,000,$65,456 (space between currency values is optional)
$200,000, $525, $60000,$120,000, $65,456
```

Some of the invalid input values,

```
$200,000,$525,$60000,$120,000,$65,456, (Trailing comma)
$200,000,,$525,$60000.$120,000,$65,456,, etc
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The solution I am looking at is a pure reg ex solution (better than what I have written above), so that I can fire validations as soon as erroneous inputs are entered by the user.

Comment: Why not just use String.Split(new string[] {",$"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: You may split with a comma, make sure there are 5 items, and make sure each trimmed item matches the shorter expression like `^\$[0-9]{1,3}(?:[,.]?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$`. BTW, what do you mean by C# and JS tags? Do you want the same solution to work in JS and C#? Also, if it works, what is the *problem*?

Comment: Are you trying to match or validate or both?

Comment: If your solution works, you should re-frame the question with modifications needed that you want in solution..

Comment: as pointed by @revo, there are some negative cases that will be matched. will update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

If you want to match while validating prices you could do this which follows:

- Including both dot and comma for formatting prices
- Max one space character between prices

```
^\$\d+([,.]\d{3})*( ?, ?\$\d+([,.]\d{3})*){4}$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/kqxFNz/2)

**Breakdown**:

- `^` Match start of input string (or line if `m` flag is set)
- `\$\d+` Match a `$` that preceds a number of digits
- `(` Start of grouping (`#1`)

  - `[,.]\d{3}` Match a period or comma that preceds 3 digits
- `)*` End of grouping (`#1`), match at least zero time
- `(` Start of grouping (`#2`)

  - `?, ?` Match a comma surrounded by optional spaces (one space at either side)
  - `\$\d+` Match a `$` that preceds a number of digits
  - `([,.]\d{3})*` Match a period or comma that preceds 3 digits (thousand separator), match at least zero time
- `){4}` End of grouping (`#2`), repeat exactly 4 times
- `$` End of input string (or line if `m` flag is set)

JS code:

```js
var re = /^\$\d+([,.]\d{3})*( ?, ?\$\d+([,.]\d{3})*){4}$/g;

var prices = ['$200,000,$525,$60000,$120,000,$65,456',
'$200,000, $525, $60000,$120,000, $65,456',
'$200,000,$525,$60000,$120,000,$65,456, ',
'$200,000,,$525,$60000.$120,000,$65,456,,'];

prices.forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(s + " => " + Boolean(s.match(re)))
})
```

Comment: There you go. Will wait for some more time before accepting this as an answer. BTW, thanks for that previous comment, that test case was completely missed by me.

Comment: I'll break down the regex to be more understandable this way you will be able to choose between answers and improve it later.

Comment: Thanks @revo that breakdown helps.

Answer (score 1):

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/2GKRdj/2) is a simpler version of what you're trying to achieve:

```
^(?:\$\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*[,.] ?){4}\$\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*$
 -------------------------------
```

- The underlined part matches 4 "prices" as you've defined, followed by a dot/comma and an optional space.
- The rest matches the last "price".

Please let me know if something is unclear

Answer (score 1):

The most prevalent character to base the pattern on is `\$` (escaped), whether it is the first character of the string or preceded by a comma (optionally followed by whitespace), that is done using `(?:^|,)\s*`. After that you want any number of digits, which is `\d+`, optionally followed by a comma which is immediately followed by digits again; `,\d+`.

Combining these, you'd get; `/(?:^|,)\s*(\$\d+(?:,\d+)?)/g`

```js
const pattern = /(?:^|,|\.)\s*(\$\d+(?:,\d+)?)/g;

const test = [
  '$200,000,$525,$60000,$120,000,$65,456',
  '$200,000, $525, $60000,$120,000, $65,456',
  '$200,000,$525,$60000,$120,000,$65,456,',
  '$200,000,,$525,$60000.$120,000,$65,456,,',
];

const matches = test.reduce((carry, string) => {
  let match = null;
  while (match = pattern.exec(string)) {
    carry.push(match[1]);
  }
  return carry;
}, []);

console.log(matches);
```

Added the extra examples from the modified question, including the `.` which now appeared as separator (`$200,000,,$525,$60000.$120,000,$65,456,,`) and modified the pattern in the example to account for this.